# combineByKey on a Dstream throws an error

Tags: scala, spark-streaming, rdd, dstream

I have a dstream with tuples `(String, Int)` in it

When I try `combineByKey`, it says me to specify parameter: *Partitioner*

```
my_dstream.combineByKey(
      (v) => (v,1),
      (acc:(Int, Int), v) => (acc._1 + v, acc._2 + 1),
      (acc1:(Int, Int), acc2:(Int, Int)) => (acc1._1 + acc2._1, acc1._2 + acc2._2)
    )
```

However, when I use it on an rdd, it works correctly:

```
 my_dstream.foreachRDD( rdd =>
      rdd.combineByKey(
        (v) => (v,1),
        (acc:(Int, Int), v) => (acc._1 + v, acc._2 + 1),
        (acc1:(Int, Int), acc2:(Int, Int)) => (acc1._1 + acc2._1, acc1._2 + acc2._2)
      ))
```

Where can I get this *partitioner* ?

Comment: side question: any particular reason why you would like to do this instead of `dstream.map(e => (e,1)).reduceByKey(_+_)` ?

Comment: Specifically, I want to calculate multiple values grouped by key. So I need to use `combineByKey` instead of `reduceByKey`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Where can I get this partitioner ?

You can create it yourself. Spark comes out of the box with two partitioners: [`HashPartitioner`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/api/scala/org/apache/spark/HashPartitioner.html) and [`RangePartitioner`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/api/scala/org/apache/spark/RangePartitioner.html). The default is the former. You can instantiate via it's constructor, you'll need to pass the number of desired partitions:

```
val numOfPartitions = // specify the amount you want
val hashPartitioner = new HashPartitioner(numOfPartitions)

my_dstream.combineByKey(
  (v) => (v,1),
  (acc:(Int, Int), v) => (acc._1 + v, acc._2 + 1),
  (acc1:(Int, Int), acc2:(Int, Int)) => (acc1._1 + acc2._1, acc1._2 + acc2._2), 
                                        hashPartitioner
)
```

Comment: I dont nkow how many partitions should I use. So:
 1) can I avoid using partitioner on a Dstream?
 2) if no, based on what should I choose number of partitions?

Comment: @Vadym No, you can't avoid the partitioner. [This blog](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/03/how-to-tune-your-apache-spark-jobs-part-2/) has a nice ballpark figure of how to partition your data